# In Access, how to Identify Dates Outside of a Range

Tags: date, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I got tasked with a project at work in Access, and I am pretty unfamiliar with it. What I'd like to do is create some kind of query or macro or vba code that looks at a table I set up with dates that an event occurred and reference a certain range (say, now-30 days), and if the date that the event occurred is outside of the range, then add it to a separate table. The thing is, certain event occur more frequently then others (some occur every 90 days, some occur every 7).

[image]

In the picture, event 4 occurs many times, but I only want it to look at the most recent one (I have since changed the numbers to actual names of what event took place).

I have played around with some date code already, I got the notation from this website:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-Access-queries-AEA83B3B-46EB-43DD-8689-5FC961F21762

The other problem I've been running into is that I would like to have it only look at the most recent event. I have been playing around with this code, as I saw on another thread:

[MS Access query - select most recent date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308778/ms-access-query-select-most-recent-date)

```
Select cleaning, Max(Date1) as most_recent
From CleaningLog
Group by Cleaning;
```

But it keeps telling me that there's a compile error, and it highlight the name of the column "Cleaning".

I haven't been able to make anything useful for either problem. If someone could help, it would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**

The date is coming from a form here, where the user types in the date that the event occurred.

[image]

Comment: Is the type of Date1 text or date?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth It's coming from a different form, so I think it's a text. I updated the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should work - if after all you copy it to the *SQL pane* of new query and not into a code module (which is where you would get a compile error).

If the values really are text, convert these to true date values with CDate. Never handle dates as strings, no exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, I had it in vba!